# How to get leading zeros for zipcode in Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

the zip is an integer datatype. so far i have

```
 select substring('00000'||cast(zip as char(5)), character_length(cast(zip as char(5))),5)
```

Comment: This is giving you what?

Answer (score 2):

It's not entirely clear what you are asking, but my guess from looking at your attempt is that you are trying to prefix a string with zeros to make it a common length.

For instance, if you have the following numbers: `123, 1564, 12413` and you would like them all to be 10 characters with repeated 0's prefixed like `0000000123, 0000001564, 0000012413`, you will need something like:

```
SELECT substring('0000000000' FROM 1 FOR 10 - LENGTH(<yourField>)) || <yourField>
```

Comment: Hi JNevill. The zipcode field in the Teradata is integer. I was trying to pad zipcode with 0 if they were only 4 digits. 01234. how would you do this in teradata? SELECT RIGHT('000'+CAST(field AS VARCHAR(3)),3)

Comment: Instead of <yourField> use your cast statement, and instead of `10-Length(` use `5-Length(` So it will look like:  `Substring('0000000000' FROM 1 FOR 5-LENGTH(CAST(zipCode AS Varchar(10)))) || Cast(zipCode as Varchar(10))`

Answer (score 1):

Apply a FORMAT to the zip:

```
TRIM(CAST(zip AS FORMAT '9(5)'))
```

or use LPAD in TD14:

```
LPAD(TRIM(zip), 5, '0')
```